# Are the usual polar coordinates actually diffeomorphisms?

Tags: integration, continuity, smooth-manifolds, polar-coordinates, diffeomorphism

Lets have look at the usual polar coordinates in two dimensions, given by the mapping
$$\Phi:(0, \infty)\times(-\pi,\pi)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2\backslash (-\infty,0]\times\{0\}, \Phi (r, \theta) = (r \sin\theta, r\cos\theta) $$

Almost everywhere are polar coordinates like this claimed to be diffeomorphisms. For example in integration, or as parametrisations of manifolds. But actually, they aren't because the inverse map is not continuous (around every point on $(-\infty,0]\times\{0\}$ in our example).

Well you could possibly fix that by restriction and using a second map but rotated, but nobody does that right? Or am I wrong? For example if you integrate over a manifold like a ball in 3D you would need to use a partition of 1 and at least 2 polar coordinate mappings to make everything correct. Why does everybody ignore that fact?

Comment: No point from the set $(-\infty,0]\times\{0\}$ is in the image of $\Phi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $\Phi$ is a diffeomorphism from $(0, \infty) \times (-\pi, \pi)$ to $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus (-\infty, 0] \times \{0\}$. Since points in $(-\infty, 0] \times \{0\}$ are excluded, we do not care if inverse function is continuous there. In fact, the inverse function would not be defined on $(-\infty, 0] \times \{0\}$.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right, I had in mind to take a ball around a point of the out cutted line and thought that the preimages of that ball (because it is intersecting with the image of $\Phi$) had to be close together for a small enough ball but yeah of course that doesn't have to be satisfied for balls centered at such points because they are not in the image of $\Phi$.